# Compound a CSS transform on interval using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, css-animations

I have a very simple interval timer that adds a transform to a paragraph of text every 2000ms:

```
setInterval(function(){
$("p").css({"-webkit-transform": "translate3d(0, -60px, 0)", "transform": "translate3d(0, -60px, 0)"});
}, 2000);
```

I would like the translate value to compound on the element on each iteration (-60px, -120px, -180px)...

How could I achieve this in the simplest way, without creating multiple classes?

Comment: A counter variable and string concatenation …?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you right, you want to subtract 60px each 2 seconds.
You can do that like this:

```
var px = 0
setInterval(function(){
  px = px - 60;
  $("p").css({
    "transform": "translate3d(0px," + px + "px, 0px)"
  });
}, 2000);
```

What this is doing is subtracting 60 every 2 seconds from the variable `px`.

Just change the numbers to change the amount or interval.

Comment: Glad to help :)